# javascript ajax not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

I have following javascript code

```
        alert("");

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "lp.aspx", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

And my server code is following

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["pb"] != null) 
    {
        Response.Redirect("main.aspx");
    }
}
```

The problem is when I concatinate query string with my javascript ajax request like following

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "lp.aspx?pb=true", true);
```

It stops sending request to the server. I mean when I debug the page the page_load event is not firing.,

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Nothing looks wrong with code. Are there error in browser console ?

Comment: What browser are you using? I tried with chrome, set a breakpoint in the if(Request.QueryString["pb"] != null) and the code stopped there.

Answer (score 0):

It was because the response.redirect was not working.

Removed it and instead used window.location in javascript